# Is there a method to sort an NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsstring

Does anyone know if there is a method to sort an NSString of ASCII characters? Ideally, I would like a method that checks to see if one string is a permutation of another, so my idea is to sort both strings in a canonical fashion and then compare them. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is what I am after more precisely. I want a method that takes two `NSStrings` as input and returns a `BOOL`:

```
- (BOOL)isPermutation:(NSString *)string1 
             ofString:(NSString *)string2;
```

The returned value should be `YES` if one string can be rearranged into the other string and `NO` otherwise.

The **NSStrings are arbitrary strings with ASCII characters**, not sentences or numbers or words. Just arbitrary strings with ASCII characters.

Comment: Do you know anything about the contents of the strings?  Are they ASCII, for example?

Comment: Yes, the characters are ASCII, but not just letters and/or numbers.

Comment: What does "sorting a string" mean? You want words alphabetized? You want all the characters completely rearranged in some deterministic order?

Comment: I don't care how it is sorted so long as it is canonical: choose any order for the characters as you like, then always sort into that order.

Comment: @Joe Blow... I am not working with words, just NSStrings of ASCII characters. I do not want to find permutations; I want to compare two strings and return YES if they are permutations of one another and NO otherwise.

Comment: It is extremely easy to sort a string using the correct iOS localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: comparator. **I have tested the standard approach, see below, and it runs at 15,000 Hz.**  Case closed, **your original idea is the only way to do it**, if "software engineering" means anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really need to sort to check this? Consider the algorithm.

```
create 2 counter arrays, ac and bc, both of size 128
initialize them with 0
for each char c in string a make ac[c]++
for each char c in string b make bc[c]++
if all 128 counters in ac and bc are same, then they r permutation of one another
```

This may even run faster then sorting.

EDIT: This is a possible implementation. As I have not compiled the code, there might be minor errors.

```
- (BOOL)isPermutation:(NSString *)string1 ofString:(NSString *)string2 {
    if ([string1 length] != [string2 length]) {
        return FALSE;    
    }

    NSInteger counter1[128];
    NSInteger counter2[128];
    NSInteger i;
    NSInteger len = [string1 length];

    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        counter1[i] = counter2[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unichar ch1 = [string1 characterAtIndex:i];
        unichar ch2 = [string2 characterAtIndex:i];
        counter1[ch1]++;
        counter2[ch2]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        if (counter1[i] != counter2[i]) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Nice for 7 bit ascii, not so good for NSString;   for NSString, you may be dealing with characters that are up to 32 bits in length....

Comment: @bbum, the OP says his strings are ASCII.  @taskinoor - this algorithm is a lot smarter, I like it.

Comment: Actually I wrote this answer after the confirmation that the strings contain only ASCII.

Comment: Oh -- I totally dig the algorithm, definitely.

Comment: @Peng Wow, in terms of making a poor engineering decision, the situation is worse than I guessed!  The "standard, iOS" routine runs amazingly quickly, at about 15,000 Hz. (iPad1.)  Task, I was able to get the routine you present there running at 30x faster.  15kHz is case closed, the standard routine should be used in any situation calling for reliability.  *(Of course, use a low level routine for scientific computing, fast loops, etc.)*

Answer (score 2):

If your characters are always ASCII, you can grab the bytes out, and then use one of the POSIX sort routines on them:

```
char myCString[[myNSString length] + 1];
memcpy(myCString, [myNSString UTF8String], [myNSString length]);

qsort(myCString, [myNSString length], 1, compareChars);
```

Where `compareChars()` is a function you've written to do the character-to-character comparison - probably as simple as `<` in this case.

Comment: What if `myString` is longer than 100 bytes?

Comment: @mipadi, super not safe in that case. =)  I just thought `char myCString[[myString length] + 1]` looked terrible.  I'll edit that back in.

Comment: Since we were engaged in a discussion of writing to memory that one shouldn't be writing to... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean, sorting the letters within a string? There's not a method on `NSString`, but it'd be pretty easy to create one. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/896807) a quick-and-dirty example (you might need to adapt it to your purposes):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int compare_char(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if (*a > *b) {
        return 1;
    } else if (*a < *b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@interface NSString (Sorting)
- (NSString *)stringBySortingCharacters;
@end

@implementation NSString (Sorting)
- (NSString *)stringBySortingCharacters
{
    const char *s = [self UTF8String];
    char *s2 = (char *) calloc([self length]+1, 1);
    if (!s2) return nil;
    strncpy(s2, s, [self length]);
    qsort(s2, [self length], 1, compare_char);
    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s2];
    free(s2);
    return ret;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *s1 = @"string";
    NSString *s2 = @"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    printf("Sorted: %s\n", [[s1 stringBySortingCharacters] UTF8String]);
    printf("Sorted: %s\n", [[s2 stringBySortingCharacters] UTF8String]);

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Carl Norum: I'm pretty sure you can ;) (In this context, `const` doesn't really mean that much. A C compiler would prevent reassignment of the constant variable within its scope, but when used in another scope, the compiler has no idea it was declared as `const`.)

Comment: @mipadi - unless it ends up in a write-protected region of memory.  Discarding the `const` qualifier and attempting to modify that object causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Carl Norum: True. Almost certainly, though, there won't be an issue with the return value of `-[NSString UTF8String]`. This is a bit of an abuse of C; if it's an issue, one could always make a (mutable) copy of the return value.

Comment: @mipadi - the return value isn't the problem.  The problem is attempting to sort the characters you got from the *original* string.  The `const char *` pointer you get to that UTF8 string is *not* safe to modify.  You had to add that cast to `(void *)` to discard the qualifier without a warning, and there's a reason that warning was presented.

Comment: @Carl Norum: It's a quick example. But yes, copying the string would be wise.

Comment: @mipadi - the edit looks good, except that `s2` leaks.  I just wanted to clarify the potential danger spot for anyone copy/pasting your code.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Your solution works, but why create an `NSMutableArray` object *and* a string object for each letter in the string, and *then* sort each object, and *then* join the array back into a string, when you can just grab the array of chars, pass it to `qsort` (a pretty commonly-used C stdlib function) and turn *that* back into a string? C might be madness, but one could argue that creating a whole bunch of temporary objects just to sort letters is also madness. This method is also pretty easy to unit test.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Why do you think using C means you "lose all engineering stability"?

Comment: @Joe Blow: Your code sample is, in my own tests, 27 times slower. It also uses a lot more memory. I ask again, why is a method that is (a) slower and (b) uses more memory preferable to my own? Sure, your code is, in most cases, "good enough", but what makes it significantly *better*?

Comment: @Joe Blow: As I said, your code is "good enough". I don't dispute that. However, you are the one that first asserted that your code was "better", so the onus is on *you* to explain *why* it is better. The closest you've come is a suggestion that C code is somehow inferior to an Objective-C solution. I never made any criticism of your code, while you asserted that my sample lacked "engineering stability" (whatever that means) and that yours, despite being slower and using much more memory, was definitively *better*. ...

Comment: ... Both of our methods will work and will be efficient enough in the vast majority of cases, but I take umbrage to the claim that, given that both pieces of code *work*, mine is significantly inferior to yours when it has far better performance. You keep saying that reliability is important, but what makes your code sample much more reliable than mine?

Comment: @Joe Blow: You do know that Objective-C is implemented on top of a C-based runtime, yes? (Check out `/usr/include/objc` sometime.) Also, if you're averse to using C, how do you use CoreFoundation? How did you interface with QuickTime pre-Snow Leopard? How do you generate random numbers? Do you never use any functions in your Objective-C code? Do you never make use of OpenGL in your apps? And why this code be rejected in an App Store (or Mac App Store) program? I don't know where you work, but I can assure you that where *I* work, I wouldn't be fired for writing more efficient, *readable* code.

Comment: @Joe Blow: I've been writing Mac software for over five years. You keep asserting that somehow, C code makes a program unreliable, but you haven't asserted *why*. Do you think the C standard library that ships with OS X is poorly written? I would wager that just about every Mac app uses "pure C" in some way (and, since the Objective-C runtime is implemented in C, you can argue that *every* Mac or iPhone app uses C).

Comment: @Joe Blow: I still don't understand why a solution using a C stdlib function is more brittle than a Cocoa-only solution. Given that you keep referring to my code as "machine code" or "assembler" [sic] when it's C code (which is commonly used in Mac OS X and iOS apps), I'm of the opinion that you're simply not knowledgeable about, and perhaps fearful of, C.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Yes, the issues were resolved. But it was also just an example for the user. At any rate, *you* still haven't specified why a Cocoa-only solution is automatically superior to one that uses C stdlib functions.

Comment: @mipadi BTW you keep referring to C stdlib functions and qsort.  For sure, **those are about as reliable and ready-to-go as anything in computing.** That's not the issue in itself.  But as soon as you use UTF8String string and pass over in to raw memory, you have lost all the solidness of Cocoa.  This, again, is exactly why the issues that came up, came up.  What I am saying is very simple - of course, just using NSString, NSArray is brutally more reliable (and brutally less performance oriented -- which does not matter in the slightest) than tooling around with C strings, machine code, etc.

Comment: Although I concur that it's not possible to be a good Objective-C coder unless you have a deep understanding of good old C and its standard library, Jon Blow deserves some slack. His solution may be the more readable and maintanable one for a "pure" Objective-C programmer. If performance is not a concern, I favor simplicity and hiding of the implementation details. His solution is "conceptually simpler".

Comment: @rsanchezsaez: Meh, that wasn't the issue. Unfortunately Joe Blow deleted almost all of his comments in this thread, so the actual context/issue has been lost to the sands of time.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. No offense intended to your nice solution, just airing some thoughts. :-)